# Microsoft sql select distinct certain columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am changing mysql queries to microsoft sql server 2008 queries, and in order to apply limit I need to select a `ROW_NUMBER()` that accumlates over each row and then apply a where condition `WHERE RowNum >= 0 AND RowNum < 0 + 20` to select a certain limit with offset.

My issue however is that I can no longer select distinct because I have a column `RowNum` that is different with each row, here's my query:

```
USE mydatabase
GO

WITH Results_CTE
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT C.firstname
        ,C.lastname
        ,C.id AS clientid
        ,QC.category_name
        ,QR.id
        ,QR.cid
        ,QR.catid
        ,QR.rhid
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY QR.id DESC
            ) AS RowNum
    FROM cms_question_report QR
        ,cms_clients C
        ,cms_questioncategory QC
    WHERE C.id = QR.cid
        AND QR.catid = '3'
        AND QR.catid = QC.id
    )
SELECT *
FROM Results_CTE
WHERE RowNum >= 0
    AND RowNum < 0 + 20
```

And the results are:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦═══════════════╦═══════╦═════╦═══════╦══════╦════════╗
║ firstname ║ lastname ║ clientid ║ category_name ║  id   ║ cid ║ catid ║ rhid ║ RowNum ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═══════╬══════╬════════╣
║ test      ║ testing  ║      121 ║ Activity Log  ║ 81499 ║ 121 ║     3 ║    0 ║     19 ║
║ test      ║ testing  ║      121 ║ Activity Log  ║ 81498 ║ 121 ║     3 ║    0 ║     20 ║
║ test      ║ testing  ║      121 ║ Activity Log  ║ 81497 ║ 121 ║     3 ║    0 ║     21 ║
║ test      ║ test     ║      120 ║ Activity Log  ║ 81496 ║ 120 ║     3 ║    0 ║     22 ║
║ test      ║ test     ║      120 ║ Activity Log  ║ 81495 ║ 120 ║     3 ║    0 ║     23 ║
║ test      ║ test     ║      120 ║ Activity Log  ║ 81494 ║ 120 ║     3 ║    0 ║     24 ║
║ test      ║ test     ║      120 ║ Activity Log  ║ 81493 ║ 120 ║     3 ║    0 ║     25 ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩═══════════════╩═══════╩═════╩═══════╩══════╩════════╝
```

I took an example from the middle of the result. What I'm after is for example:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦═══════════════╦═══════╦═════╦═══════╦══════╦════════╗
║ firstname ║ lastname ║ clientid ║ category_name ║  id   ║ cid ║ catid ║ rhid ║ RowNum ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═══════╬══════╬════════╣
║ test      ║ testing  ║      121 ║ Activity Log  ║ 81497 ║ 121 ║     3 ║    0 ║     21 ║
║ test      ║ test     ║      120 ║ Activity Log  ║ 81496 ║ 120 ║     3 ║    0 ║     22 ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩═══════════════╩═══════╩═════╩═══════╩══════╩════════╝
```

Where I am trying to group the results by `clientid`. How do I achieve that?

Comment: How did you chose the value for `RowNum` to be 21 and 22 or `id` to be 81497 and 81496?

Comment: Actually you can do *group by* but the problem I see is that the column id is should unique instead of client id and if there's an instances that you have different catid or rownum, for it's not a good idea to eliminate some information just to summarized the tables.

Comment: It starts from 1 and increments, i selected an example from the center of the result

Comment: @yamidemichaos I tried putting `GROUP BY C.id` at the end of the query  but I'm getting an error: `Column 'cms_clients.firstname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: @yamidemichaos and when I add `aggregate_function(C.firstname)` in the select query I get another error: `'aggregate_function' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: You can't specify `aggregate_function(C.firstname)` in the SELECT part of the query. What the error says is that you should add a `GROUP BY C.firstname` at the end of your query. This also is valid for the other list of columns in your `SELECT` part, which you also need to add to the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I did add a `GROUP BY C.firstname` at the end of my query and that gave me an error: `Column 'cms_clients.firstname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Don't give up on me :D

Comment: @SQL But how do you define the 'middle' ? Based on what logic did you chose those two specific records to be shown?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I didn't create the query itself from scratch, I'm only converting it to microsoft sql and adjusting it there, however the fields that are being retrieved are all previewed in the front end page.

Comment: @SQL So, you don't know what its supposed to show? Can you also post the MySQL query? I think that would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
USE ctarspla_mercycs
GO
WITH Results_CTE AS
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CLIENTID DESC) AS RowNum 
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
        C.firstname, 
        C.lastname, 
        C.id as clientid, 
        QC.category_name, 
        QR.catid, 
        QR.rhid 
        FROM 
        cms_question_report QR, 
        cms_clients C, 
        cms_questioncategory QC 
        WHERE C.id=QR.cid 
        AND QR.catid=3 
        AND QR.catid=QC.id) t1)
SELECT * FROM Results_CTE 
WHERE RowNum >= 0 
AND RowNum < 0 + 20
```